# Can we compress a large file as a chunk data for GZIP in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I saw the sample APIas below

```
public static byte[] compress( byte[] data )
{   
    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzipStream = new GZIPOutputStream( baos, 6, GZIPOutputStream.MAX_LOG2_WINDOW_LENGTH );
        gzipStream.write( data );
        gzipStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

But when I tried to compress with a large file with Curve 8900 OS 4.6, I got a "OutOfMemoryError" so I would like to know that how to compress as a chunk small data?

I already tried with this code as below but it doesn't work, compressed file cannot decompress...

```
file = (FileConnection)Connector.open(_fileOutputPath, Connector.READ_WRITE);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.create();
            }
            os = file.openOutputStream();
            is = FileUtil.getInputStream(_fileInputPath, 0);
            int tmpSize = 1024;           
            byte[] tmp = new byte[tmpSize];
            int len = -1;
            gzipStream = new GZIPOutputStream( os, 6, GZIPOutputStream.MAX_LOG2_WINDOW_LENGTH );
            while((len = is.read(tmp, 0, tmpSize)) != -1) {
                gzipStream.write(tmp, 0, len);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

GZIPOutputStream does not produce a file suitable for use with the gzip command line tool.  This is because it doesn't produce the necessary file headers.   How did you test decompressing it?   You should write a similar Java program that makes use of GZIPInputStream to test, as 'gunzip' is not going to recognize the input.

Comment: Re-reading the docs, I think this is wrong - RFC 1952 specifies the gzip file format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the first code sample is that the ByteArrayOutputStream is getting too big for the limited memory of a mobile device.

An option could be to first write to a file (for instance) on SD card.

The second code sample seems fine, but see Michael's answer.